Pass Customer ID From Frontend to Custom Remix Endpoint In Shopify
I am building an app on shopify with remix. Currently i am trying to send Current Customer ID to the api endpoint defined in remix app. The issue i am facing is regarding to the endpoint. It is giving an error of 404. I would like to know is it possible to send customer id from frontend to custom shopify app endpoint.
Here is the code where i am requesting from frontend :


  async function sendCustomerIdToBackend(customerId) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/customer-id', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ customerId }),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        const errorData = await response.json();
        console.error('Error:', errorData);
      } else {
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log('Response from backend:', data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Fetch Error:', error);
    }
  }

  // Example usage
  sendCustomerIdToBackend(4242424242);



And this is my customer-id.jsx file which is given in api folder under routes of my app


import { json } from "@remix-run/node";

export const action = async ({ request }) => {
  const { customerId } = await request.json();

  if (!customerId) {
    return json({ error: "Customer ID is required" }, { status: 400 });
  }

  return json({ message: `Received customer ID: ${customerId}` });
};




You should use the loader function to send response from backend, Moreover, you can send the customerId from frontend in the URL:
Heres how your backend API will look like:
import { json } from "@remix-run/node";

export const loader = async ({ request }) => {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  const customerId = url.searchParams.get("customerId");

  if (!customerId) {
    return json({ error: "Customer ID is required" }, { status: 400 });
  }

  return json({ message: `Received customer ID: ${customerId}` });
};

You no longer need to make a POST request, a GET request will do the trick. Your updated frontend code will be like:
async function sendCustomerIdToBackend(customerId) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/customer?customerId=${customerId}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Fetch Error:', error);
    }
  }

  sendCustomerIdToBackend(4242424242);

